# Best Way to run a program on 2 different files at once

Tags: python

I have built a python script that consumes a file and does various things with it.

On a daily basis I need this run on 2 separate files. What is the best way to do this?

Is it best to duplicate the code in the program or to put it into a function and run that twice in the script?

Comment: Run the program twice without changing anything?

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, *never* write duplicate code if you can accomplish it with a function. Always write "dry" code.

The best way to do this would be to define a function that runs whatever needs to be run, and just call that function twice.